# How to find the Big-O complexity mentioned below

Tags: java, big-o

Could you guys help in understanding the time complexity of the below code -

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = N; i > 0; i /= 2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

It was my underdstanding that this should be O(nlogn) but that is wrong. 
Just to update why I thought it would be O(nlogn) because in the first loop, we are dividing the i by 2 meaning we are cutting it in half, so that would be log n and in the inner loop we are running it till i, so it would be N, so complexity would be O(nlogn)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Every for is considered n complexity, so if there's one inside another the complexity in n squared. But in this case, you need to check what are you passing through the fors and make the sum of the 2 complexities

Comment: Looking at `count` for various values of `N` will give you a clue. (Oh, go on then: https://ideone.com/8GH8Me)

Comment: For questions like that I'd love if there was LaTeX support in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ÓscarContreras That is incorrect. What about this `for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)` which actually has logarithmic complexity because of the step-width. Or what about `for(foo(); bar(); baz())`, well this completely depends on the methods. What about `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { for (int j = i; j < i + 5; j++) {...}}`, this is not quadratic but linear. Do not just learn by pattern, you have to actually understand how big-o works and correctly analyse it.

Comment: @akuzminykh You do have a point there. I think what this question lacks to be a good question is an explanation of why OP thinks it is `O(n log n)`, that would demonstrate an attempt and then people could focus on clearing misunderstandings rather than just explain *everything* and maybe even skim over the part that is actually confusing OP. But I suppose this is the wrong place for such a discussion, should probably go to meta.

Answer (score 20):

The inner loop is easy - goes each time from 0 till j. so now we only need to understand what j is on each iteration.
The outer loop starts with N and cut in half each time, so it means that the first round will be N, the second N/2, the third N/4 and so on.

So we have N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 .... which sums up to 2N operations. So the complexity is o(N)

Comment: Hi. When there is a loop within a loop, shouldn’t we multiply the iterations instead of adding them ?

Comment: @HemanthAnnavarapu - if we are talking about iterations of a constant size (i.e. 1->n and 1->k) than yes, N*K whould be the answer. but since each iteration here is of a different size, multiply wont work

Comment: So if the iteration are different, then we won't multiply the two loops? So the first loop if going from N -> N/2 -> N/4 and so on and the inner loop is iterating from N , N/2 and so on. So I understand the inner loop comes about 2N when adding it but what about the first loop?

Answer (score 11):

As others have pointed out, each time the outer loop iterates, the inner loop performs half of the iterations, starting by N:

```
N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 ...
```

That will go on until a division is 0.
However, in terms of upper-bound complexity, it is typical to consider the case of the infinity, that means, imagining that the series goes on and on and on... but we can find a converging value.

In this particular case, we find that, extracting the common factor, we're left with:

```
N * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 ...)
```

The first thing is just N, and the second factor is a geometric series, which terms are of the form 1/2^n. ([formula and further explanation here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula))

In short term, that second factor, the infinite sum, converges to 2. So in total we have 2N, which in terms of complexity is equivalent to N.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the complexity is `O(2N)` which is equivalent to `O(N)`.

Why:

You have 2 loops, the outer one gets half of N each time (except the first round) and the inner one goes from 0 to that half of N, which indicates in the first inner loop it goes `[0, N)` then `[0, N/2)`, `[0, N/4)`, ...

Therefore total number of times is `N + N/2 + N/4 + ...` equals to `N * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...)` and since [`1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...` tends to `2` when N approaches infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), the original expression tends to 2N.

Answer (score 1):

The second for-loop while be executed `N + N/2 + N/4 +....+ N/N`

, the first for-loop decides how much the second for-loop will be executed.

When i = 0, j loops until N

, i = N/2, j loops until N/2

, And so on

, The Big O notation of `N + N/2 + N/4 +....+ N/N` will be `O(N)`

Answer (score 1):

One of the common mistakes of people when they approach to these tasks are looking at things as "straightforward", But this is not the case on many scenarios (like this one).

The right way to figure out the time complexity (also in memory complexity) is trying to "follow" the steps of calculation the program will execute and how much time each step will take.

I would recommend writing down what will happen at the first 5+- iterations and try to see what is the pattern.

So, in this case, the first loop is gonna start from N until 0 while the index is reduced by half each iteration. You were right that it implies for `O(log(N))`, but lets write the index down for some of the first iterations:

```
i=N
i=N/2
i=N/4
i=N/8
i=N/16
...
```

Now, the real thing happens in the second `for` which inside the first loop.
First, you can see that the second index `j` has a dependency with `i` which should immediately raise a red flag and we should pay special attention to it.
The second loop goes from 0 to `i` of the current iteration with increment of one. At first, you would probably say it is `O(n)` because the change is an increment of one and it goes from 0 to a specific known integer. But since that integer is dynamically change, you can't really say that, and you must know what `i` is gonna be.
So lets write the first iterations of the inner loop for each of the iterations above:

```
i=N       ->  |  j=0  |  j=1  |  j=2  | ... |  j=N    |
i=N/2     ->  |  j=0  |  j=1  |  j=2  | ... |  j=N/2  |
i=N/4     ->  |  j=0  |  j=1  |  j=2  | ... |  j=N/4  |
i=N/8     ->  |  j=0  |  j=1  |  j=2  | ... |  j=N/8  |
i=N/16    ->  |  j=0  |  j=1  |  j=2  | ... |  j=N/16 |
...
```

Now, each "box" (`|    |`) I wrote above is a step the program executes. As I said before, we need to know also how much time each step is gonna take. In this case, each step (each iteration) includes one operation of variable (`count`) increment, which we consider as `O(1)` (a constant).

The last thing we should do is to sum up all the steps we mentioned above with their costs:

First row will run N times (0,1,2,..,N) - each time the step will cost `O(1)`. -> So it's going to be `N*1 = N`
Second row will run N/2 times (0,1,2,..,N/2) - each time the step will cost `O(1)`. -> So it's going to be `(N/2)*1 = N/2`
Third row will run N/4 times (0,1,2,..,N/4) - each time the step will cost `O(1)`. -> So it's going to be `(N/4)*1 = N/4`
And so on..

When we sum it up, the program cost will be: `N+(N/2)+(N/4)+(N/8)+...+~(N/N) = N * ( 1 + (1/2) + (1/4) + (1/8) +... )`
`( 1 + (1/2) + (1/4) + (1/8) +... )` is a simple known math series. (You can get help from some websites or little google search to learn the results of those or more complicated series).
This one Equals to `2-(2/N)` at most.

So the final cost will be: `N * ( 2 - (2/N) ) = 2N - 2` which is `O(N)` overall.

This answer is pretty long and well detailed for this question but I was trying to show a "way of thinking" more than just solving the problem. I hope it helped you (and others) to think different on questions like these, Trying to take each `loop` and each step and check carefully **how many** steps are going to happen here and more importantly (and mostly forgotten) what is the **cost** of each step.

Answer (score 0):

For a input integer n, the innermost statement is executed following times.

```
n + n/2 + n/4 + … 1
```

So time complexity T(n) can be written as

```
T(n) = O(n + n/2 + n/4 + … 1) = O(n)
```

you may refer this : [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/algorithms-analysis-of-algorithms-question-3/)